# Specify a file to be compiled first to generate precompile headers in Visual Studio Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a file (ABC.cpp) in my project for which i need to create a precompile header (ABC.pch). Rest of the file in the project is suppose to use ABC.pch.

Now to make this work i need to compile ABC.cpp before rest of the file in project is compiled. How can i ensure this in visual studio project?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the settings of your project -> C/C++ -> Precompiled Headers and define your header-file there. The option for precompile header should be set to "/Yu" (Use).

After that, you need to right-click your precompiled cpp-file (ABC.cpp), go to Settings -> C/C++ -> precompiled headers and choose "/Yc" (Create) there.

Comment: It should compile your precompiled header before everything else :) Does  it work as you want it to?

Comment: But this project earlier used MakeFile where the precompile header was generated in init i.e before any file is compiled. Now in a visual studio project this file can be compiled in any order. If a source file where i specify (/Yu) i.e  use precompile header, can be compiled before ABC.cpp is compiled. Then won't the compilation fail?

Comment: I am trying you suggestion now.

Comment: The source file where /Yc is defined will be compiled before the /Yu ones.

Comment: Yes this is what is happening. Awesome